# Text inline with stacked radio buttons in HTML

Tags: html

[[image: Needed End Result]
[[image: My Current Result]
I need to produce text with stacked radio buttons as presented in the blue image.  I have been able to figure out how to get them into a block but I am struggling to get it be inline with the text. I am sure this is an easy fix but I am not very experienced with HTML.

```
    <p>Please also tell us about yourself.</p>
    <label>I am</label>
    <div>
        <label class="block"><input type="radio" id="male" name="gender" value="Male">Male</label>
        <label class="block"><input type="radio" id="male" name="gender" value="Female">Female</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>and</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label class="block"><input type="radio" id="8less" name="age" value="8orless">8 or less</label>
        <label class="block"><input type="radio" id="9to15" name="age" value="9to15">9 to 15</label>
        <label class="block"><input type="radio" id="8less" name="age" value="16to25">16 to 25</label>
        <label class="block"><input type="radio" id="8less" name="age" value="26to40">26 to 40</label>
        <label class="block"><input type="radio" id="8less" name="age" value="41ormore">41 or more</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>years of age.</label>
    </div>
    

</form>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just wrap the entire element in a flex wrapper and align the items to the center. The radio buttons/label should be a block level element so they can stack on top of each other.

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <label>I am</label>
    <div>
        <label class="block"><input type="radio" id="male" name="gender" value="Male">Male</label>
        <label class="block"><input type="radio" id="male" name="gender" value="Female">Female</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>and</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label class="block"><input type="radio" id="8less" name="age" value="8orless">8 or less</label>
        <label class="block"><input type="radio" id="9to15" name="age" value="9to15">9 to 15</label>
        <label class="block"><input type="radio" id="8less" name="age" value="16to25">16 to 25</label>
        <label class="block"><input type="radio" id="8less" name="age" value="26to40">26 to 40</label>
        <label class="block"><input type="radio" id="8less" name="age" value="41ormore">41 or more</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>years of age.</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.block {
  display: block;
}
```